# Do signed nibbles make any sense?

Tags: c#, byte, unsigned, signed, nibble

I wrote this helper method to unpack a `byte` onto nibbles:

```
public static void Deconstruct(this byte value, out byte nibble1, out byte nibble2)
{
    nibble1 = (byte) ((value >> 00) & 0x0F);
    nibble2 = (byte) ((value >> 04) & 0x0F);
}
```

Then naturally, I thought doing the same for `sbyte` (signed byte):

```
public static void Deconstruct(this sbyte value, out byte nibble1, out byte nibble2)
{
    nibble1 = (byte) ((value >> 00) & 0x0F);
    nibble2 = (byte) ((value >> 04) & 0x0F);
}
```

But well, `sbyte` is a bit confusing to say the least.

**Question:**

When unpacking a `sbyte` (signed byte) as nibbles, should these nibbles also be signed or not?

Comment: Unsigned. Nybbles are 4 bits. If you were to consider them signed, you'd have to sign-extend them.  Those extra bits wouldn't be of any value and they'd be lost when you repack them. For simplicity, consider them unsigned, even when the packed value is signed.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. Post an answer if you want and I'll accept it.